# Using user defined types (structs) with container classes like set

Tags: c++

I'm very new to C++ and I'm trying to use a user-defined type, a struct, with a container class, which in this case is a Set.

I know that to store elements of user-defined type, which can't be compared using the built-in relational operators, I'll need to write a comparison callback function and pass it to the Set constructor. I can't figure out what the syntax for this is, though.

I have this defined in my .cpp file:

```
Set<struct> included;
```

And then this is defined in a header file:

```
struct pointT { 
int row; 
int col; 

bool operator==(PointT p1, PointT, p2) {
    return p1.x == p2.x && p1.y == p2.y;

}

};
```

Is this all I need to do, or am I missing some big here, as the code doesn't seem to compile as the type is not recognized?

I've looked on this site for similar answers, but I can't find anything specific and clear to this situation. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `Set<struct>` should probably be `Set<pointT>` for starters

Comment: what error you are getting during compilation?

Comment: `std::set` requires a less `operator<()` defined for our struct/class.

Comment: Your equality operator is wrong: When it's a member function it only takes one argument, the other object to compare to this object. Besides, you have case-sensitivity errors (`pointT` versus `PointT`), and what is `x` and `y`?

Comment: I've changed "struct" to PointT. The errors I'm getting are: PointT was not declared in this scope; Template argument is invalid; and invalid type in declaration before ; token. I will try adding the < operator and see if that changes anything, but I have a feeling the other errors have to do with something else.

Comment: @user18294: If the class is called `PointT`, then you have to call it `PointT`, not `pointT`, everywhere. C++ is case-sensitive.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg @user18294 I've now changed that to this:     `struct pointT { 
 int row; 
 int col; 
 
 bool operator==(pointT p1, pointT p2) {
  return p1.row == p2.row && p1.col == p2.col;
 
 }
 
};` I know you mentioned that it should take only one argument, but I'm not sure how to structure that -- any tips would be really helpful.

Comment: A member comparison operator (like your `operator==`, or the `operator<` that you really need) compares *`this`* object with another object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, choose a name for the class; you're calling it variously `pointT`, `PointT`, and `struct` (which isn't even a valid name). I'll just call it `point`, since I don't like weird decorations on names.

Then you need to decide on the member names: are they `row` and `col` or `x` and `y`? I'll choose the first.

To store it in `std::set` (or, in general, to use it as a key in standard associative containers), you need `operator<`, not `operator==`, since associative keys are ordered. This can either be a member function with one parameter (`this` being the left-hand operand, and the parameter being the right-hand):

```
struct point {
    int row;
    int col;

    bool operator<(point const & rhs) {
        return std::tie(row, col) < std::tie(rhs.row, rhs.col);
    }
};
```

or a non-member with two parameters:

```
bool operator<(point const & lhs, point const & rhs) {
    return std::tie(lhs.row, lhs.col) < std::tie(rhs.row, rhs.col);
}
```

Note that my example implementation needs the C++11 `<tuple>` header, and assumes you want a lexicographical ordering (or don't particularly care about the ordering). If you're stuck in the past, then you'll need to write it yourself; something like:

```
bool operator<(point const & lhs, point const & rhs) {
    if (lhs.row < rhs.row) return true;
    if (rhs.row < lhs.row) return false;
    return lhs.col < rhs.col;
}
```

If your `Set` doesn't behave like a standard associative container, then it may have other requirements; but I can't guess what they might be. You'll have to consult that class's documentation.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <set>

namespace point {
    struct PointT {
        int x;
        int y;
    };

    bool operator==(const PointT& p1, const PointT& p2) {
        return p1.x < p2.x  ||  (p1.x == p2.x  &&  p1.y < p2.y);
    }

    bool operator<(const PointT& p1, const PointT& p2) {
        return p1.x < p2.x  &&  p1.y < p2.y;
    }

    bool operator<=(const PointT& p1, const PointT& p2) {
        return p1 < p2  ||  p1 == p2;
    }

    bool operator>(const PointT& p1, const PointT& p2) {
        return p2 < p1;
    }

    bool operator>=(const PointT& p1, const PointT& p2) {
        return p2 < p1  ||  p1 == p2;
    }
}


int main()
{
    using namespace point;
    std::set<PointT> s{ { 1, 2 }, { 2, 3 }, { 3, 4 }, { 4, 5 }, { 1, 2 } };
    for (const auto& e : s) std::cout << "(" << e.x << "," << e.y << ")" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: For PointT a{1,2}, b{1,1} you get a>b but !(b<a). This is counter intuitive. You should give a strict sorting order like checking x first and only comparing y if the x are equal.